# Flex accessing https service of the same domain that swf is loaded

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex4, glassfish-3

I am developing a flex application with flex 4.1 sdk and java backend (runs on Glassfish 3.1 via http). For security reasons I decided to move my authentication process to https until a session id is obtained. Therefore I changed the filter settings to use ssl for login and logout pages(just two pages due to performance reasons. The data-size sent to client is large and I do not want to slow down the system). Glassfish forwarded these pages to 8181 port (which is HTTPS port). Everything is ok for the java part. However flex defines the 8181 port as a different domain and then problems arise. Due to flash's same-origin policy it cannot load the secured content. Normally a crossdomain.xml is the solution but I am accessing content of the same domain through a different port. What will be the solution ?

Comment: Why not use the standard port for HTTPS (443) and have your swf file served through there as well?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best solution but create a subdomain that maps to 8181 and put a crossdomain.xml that will allow access from root domain.